# Getting sum of items for each unique tag in database (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with a table of devices. Each device requires a number of tests each year. The database is populated using a spreadsheet which is updated monthly. What I would like to be able to do is sum the number of pass or fails for each device and then compare it to the total number of tests the device was supposed to have. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Example: Lets say Horn A requires 2 tests per year, and these are some of the rows for horn A.

```
Device | Pass | Fail
Horn A |  1  |    0 (Jan)
Horn A |  0  |    0 (Feb)
Horn A |  1  |    0 (March)
Horn B |  1  |    0
```

And so on

By summing the number of passes and fails with Horn A, one can see that it had two tests. I'm just not sure how to make this into a proper query.

If this isn't clear, let me know

Comment: I think the query is pretty basic, but something that you don't seem to be concerned with is the fact that you are dealing with test/year, but you don't give a date/time field to measure by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, if you want to get "2" from the above data, you can do:

```
select device, count(*)
from table
where pass > 0 or fail > 0
group by device;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT Device, Sum(Pass + Fail) AS "Total Tests"
FROM table
GROUP BY Device;
```

This will ensure you can handle more than 0 or 1 in either Pass or Fail. In the case that you have 2 passes and 1 fail for a total of 3 tests in that one month entry.